# Firefox skips svg rect onload= events but IE respects them

Tags: javascript, events, svg, onload

Using this code example in Firefox (recent version) and IE11, I am getting unexpected "skips" of onload= events for SVG element `<rect>` in Firefox.  Here is my testbed code.

```
<svg x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" onload="whereIsIt('root svg')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <script type="application/javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            function whereIsIt(where) {
                alert(where);
            }
        ]]>
    </script>
    <rect x="5" y="5" height="20" width="30" fill="red" onload="whereIsIt('uncontained shape')"/>
    <svg onload="whereIsIt('containing svg')">
        <rect onload="whereIsIt('contained shape')"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

IE11 pops up the alert dialog for all four events, but FF skips events on `<rect>` but fires the other two.

I did some trial and error using `externalResourcesRequired="yes"` but that didn't seem to help.  The spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement seems clear that we'd expect onload= to be supported here.  I also checked http://caniuse.com but not clues there.

Comment: Yes, that's how Firefox works, we won't be changing that. And your question is? Why do you need an onload event on an element that doesn't load anything. What IE11 does is invalid per SVG 2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/interact.html#SVGEvents) though it was valid in SVG 1.1

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I was just trying to make sense of how it works.  onload= on an SVG element seems "reasonable" to me, it does load although there's nothing explicitly visual about it.  Thanks again for your clarification.